# Custom system restore DVD?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, partitioning, clone

I am looking for a way to make a clone of a partition on a DVD where the client will actually be able to restore the partition himself without much hassle.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have an idea -- Tell us what OS you're talking about :-)

Comment: Clearly it's AIX - he wants to clone an LPAR (partition) and then do a system restore.

Comment: Windows 7, XP, etc..

Comment: @Rushino in that case you can safely ignore MikeyB and voretaq7's responses, unless you want to do this from a Linux live CD. =)

Comment: @WesleyDavid: Huh? Linux? Neither of us were talking about Linux.

Comment: @MikeyB Technicalities. Pish posh. =P

Comment: Windows Backup + Windows Installation DVD will do this.

Comment: @Rushino - We have tags for those operating systems -- added 'em for you.  Also WesleyDavid's answer is probably the best fit for your situation :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) to make a bootable image of my machine. There are couple limitations I don't like, such as you can't restore the image onto a smaller hard drive, even if your image only has a small amount of data, and also related, if you restore onto a larger drive, you will have a partition which is the same size as the partition you backed up.  Other than that, it works great. The backup can be compressed quite small, and can be stored on a USB stick or USB hard disk for later use.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to consider two resources:

1. [The Microsoft OPK Deployment Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/training/windowsopk/Pages/index.aspx). Check out the document titled "[Creating a Hard Disk Recovery Solution for Windows 7](http://oem.microsoft.com/downloads/public/worldwide/windows_7/creating_a_windows_7_hard_disk_recovery_solution.pdf)"
2. Third party tools such as one by a company called FarStone. I won't link to it directly since I haven't tested it myself and I'm *slightly* skeptical of the website.

There aren't a ton of third party tools out there to do this, and there's probably a good reason for that. I would strongly suggest looking at the OEM Preinstallation Kit and using that as a base for making your recovery partition.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a brilliantly simple process.

The [`mksysb`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mksysb.htm) command creates an installable system image from a partition and the [`mkdvd`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mkdvd.htm) command can be used to write this image out as a bootable DVD.

With this DVD, you can restore the system to the point at which the `mksysb` snapshot was taken.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't do wrong with [dump(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dump&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and [restore(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=restore&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE).  On most modern systems you can even send the output directly to a DVD device.

If you need something a little more bare-metal there's always [dd(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), but that's nowhere near as user-friendly...